Playwright why adding cookies and klicking on accept cookies btn does not close the cookies banner. why?
I am scraping a website with playwright where I need to accept cookies (code below).

I click on the accept button:

await page.waitForSelector('#cmp')
await page.locator('#cmp').click()

when I log the html I get, what I expect is to get only the content, but I get BOTH the cookies banner text and after the content.
The problem with this: I believe because of this, I cannot correctly access the content (with cheerio) as I did before the cookies were introduced by the website.

if I also add the cookies, besides clicking on the accept button, I dont get BOTH the cookies banner text + the actual content BUT I get only the cookies content. I add them like in the code below but also tried to just look up which cookies are added manually and add them manually in the code. Both doesnt do anything.

await page.waitForSelector('#cmp')
await page.locator('#cmp').click()
const  cookies = await context.cookies() //I can see all the cookies that were 'added' after the button was clicked
await context.addCookies(cookies)

What happens:

When I dont close the browser for testing purposes I can see the page is being opened, cookies clicked, the cookies banner closes after and I see the content of the page. Seems all good but as I wrote earlier I still get the html WITH the cookies banner content.

I dont understand why. Any ideas?
The full code:
const getHtml = () => {
  const browser = await {chromium}["chromium"].launch({headless: false});
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage()
  await page.goto(url);

  await page.waitForLoadState("networkidle");

  await page.waitForSelector('#cmp')
  await page.locator('#cmp').click()
  const cookies = await context.cookies() //I can see all the cookies that were 'added' 
  after the button was clicked
  await context.addCookies(cookies)

//here below I wait for the element in the main content to appear
  await page.waitForSelector(("section[aria-labelledby='some']")) 

  const html = await page.content();
  await context.close();
  await browser.close();
  return html;
}

Update:
The html return BOTH the page content and the cookies banner content, but if I open it inside the browser its gone (is not existent in the html when looking at it in the chrome dev tools

it's possible the HTML will still be there in the DOM, but is hidden or 0x0 size.

Locators auto-wait so you can remove the await page.waitForSelector('#cmp') line. Also, cheerio is pointless if you're using Playwright, which already has a full-featured locator suite that works on the live document. In any case, without the site under test, there's not much to do to help here because I can't run the code and reproduce the problem. await context.addCookies(await context.cookies()) is pointless, adding the cookies the context already has to itself? Repost of Playwright Node :How to accept cookies when scrawling?, same remark

@ggorlen, im just using cheerio as I already have working code written and it doesnt really matter in this case. I am adding the cookies after the click event on the cookies accept btn (the cookies I get and add later with context.addCookies are exactly the same I see when I manually myself accept the cookies so Im not sure why I should not add them. I as I said also tried to just manually add the cookies, still nothing happens. Im not sure if you have another idea when you think await context.addCookies(cookies) doesnt make sense?

@thank you! I think maybe its the case. Is there anything I can do with playwright to 'unhide' it?

Same remark as last post: no page, no way to help. Every page has totally unique, arbitrary behavior, so by not providing it, you're asking people to guess blindly, which is almost impossible. You can repost this all day, but until there's a [mcve] nobody is going to be able to help you. Why do you need to accept cookies on this site? Generally you don't for most sites.

I asked if anyone had a similar issue or knows how to manage cookies. If you also dont know that, its fine but Im not sure why commenting then. Any site asks for cookies accepting, nothing special with the one im scrping.
